# Be notified of @-messages on Twitter

Tags: twitter, email, notifications

On Twitter, how can I receive an automatic notification through email if somebody writes an @-message to me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Follow the (private authenticated) RSS feed of your @replies/mentions: http://twitter.com/statuses/replies.rss - since its authenticated it will require you to sign in and won't work in Google Reader (unless you [use Yahoo Pipes as an intermediary](http://www.labnol.org/internet/private-feeds-in-google-reader/11983/))
2. Use a web-based service (such as http://pu.ly) to monitor your mentions and email you when they appear

Comment: So sad stack-sites have no pu.ly! :(

Answer (score 2):

Mention Notifier is a free service that should do the job:

http://software.engraph.com/managementionnotifier/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Twitter now supports email notifications for mentions as well others.
Check your settings to see if this feature was rolled out to you.
[image: Email notification for Mentions and Replies]

Answer (score 1):

Here's [an article that describes the process](http://www.amitbhawani.com/blog/get-twitter-replies-mentions-on-sms/).  Essentially you can use Yahoo Pipes to find replies or mentions within an RSS feed, then provide that feed to the FeedMyInbox service.

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple accounts.  I created a search for @name1 OR @name2 OR @name3 and then I subscribe to this by RSS (search, then look for the subscribe to this query button on the side of the page).

The search for @name solution does not require authentication and works in google reader.

I use the same technique to create a merged @mention column in TweetDeck because having a few mention columns will use up the whole screen.

If your name is reasonably unique, leave of the @ to capture messages from people who don't get the @ convention yet.