# How can I get all Twitter @reply messages sent to me from people I follow via SMS?

Tags: twitter, sms

I usually keep SMS for most messages off, but would like to get @reply messages so I don't miss out on any conversation opportunities. Twitter is blocked on the PCs at work, so I will often notice an @reply 8-10 hours after it is sent.

Is this possible with Twitter or a third-party server (minimal payment is OK.) ?

(This question  has some good general answers, if you dont' want SMS: [Be notified of @-messages on Twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106/be-notified-of-messages-on-twitter) )

Answer (score 1):

The following site gives one way to do it.

[Get Twitter @replies to your cell phone](http://chrisnoble.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/get-twitter-replies-to-your-cell-phone/)

There are several ways to forward @replies to your phone and most involve following the RSS or using the twitter (streaming) API to forward messages.

Answer (score 0):

One of my Twitter contacts, @[Navarr](http://twitter.com/Navarr), developed a service called [txtMyName](http://twitter.com/txtMyName) that does what you're looking for, and it's designed for use via SMS. I think you still have to contact him for an invitation, or you can see if the default access code at [the app's website](http://txtme.koneko-chan.net/) works.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't SMS, but if you have an iPhone, there is an app called Boxcar ( http://boxcar.io/ ) that is really useful for getting push notifications on various events, including twitter @ replies.